# Put a condition in java script

Tags: javascript

I need to put a condition in this code:

If the value inserted does not contain the symbol `#` in the beginning (example: `#stackoverflow`), when submited, it inserts a `#`. If the value is like `#stackoverflow` then don't need to put the `#`.

```
form.on("submit", () => {
  const networkElement = form.closest(".network");
  const channel = form.find("input[name='channel']").val();
  const key = form.find("input[name='key']").val();
  const existingChannel = utils.findCurrentNetworkChan(channel);

  if (existingChannel.length) {
    existingChannel.trigger("click");
  } else {
    socket.emit("input", {
      text: `/join ${channel} ${key}`,
      target: networkElement.find(".lobby").data("id"),
    });
  }

  closeForm(networkElement);

  return false;
});
```

Comment: You can just check the first character of the string. Assuming you are referencing the channel variable,  you can do if (channel.substring(0,1) === '#')

Comment: Thanks @tomerpacific, can you help me to insert this on "my" code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the first character of the string. Assuming you are referencing the channel variable, you can do:

```
form.on("submit", () => {
  const networkElement = form.closest(".network");
  const channel = form.find("input[name='channel']").val();
  const key = form.find("input[name='key']").val();
  const existingChannel = utils.findCurrentNetworkChan(channel);

  //Below is the logic to tell if the channel variable doesn't have the # sign in the 
  //beginning

 if (channel.substring(0,1) !== '#') {
    channel = '#' + channel;
 }

 //The code above checks if the first character isn't the # sign and if it isn't,
 //It adds it to the beginning of the string

  if (existingChannel.length) {
      existingChannel.trigger("click");
     } else {
      socket.emit("input", {
      text: `/join ${channel} ${key}`,
      target: networkElement.find(".lobby").data("id"),
    });
   }

 closeForm(networkElement);

 return false;
});
```

Comment: when I add the If condition, the form ask me if I want to leave the page, something is going wrong

Comment: @Fdcarvalho - Please post the updated code so we can see what you have edited. What you said, does not make sense.

Comment: hi, can you check it? I put the code that you give me http://prntscr.com/luw4rd

  //Below is the logic to tell if the channel variable doesn't have the # sign in the 
  //beginning

 if (channel.substring(0,1) !== '#') {
    channel = '#' + channel;
 }

Comment: I only added this:

if (channel.substring(0,1) !== '#') {
    channel = '#' + channel;
 }

Comment: @Fdcarvalho - You could be seeing that the form is closing because of the following line : closeForm(networkElement);